# How to fill an array with one character in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Instead of setting up a loop to go through each position of this array and set it equal to this dot

```
int arraySize=50;
char board[arraySize];

     for(i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
          board[i]='.';
```

Is there any way I can declare an array to be filled with these '.' right away?

e.g.   char board[arraySize]={'.'};

Comment: `char board[arraysize];` is illegal in standard C++ ; see Phillip Ngan's suggestion for a better idea.

Comment: The issue with that declaration is that you allocate memory at compile time using a size that is known only at run time. arraySize may change at anytime. If you say for example '#define ARRAY_SIZE 50' and then in the next you say 'char board[ARRAY_SIZE];' then that is fine since everything is known at compile time. Another option you allocate at runtime using new and use "value initialization" like this: 'char * board = new char[arraySize]();' This will allocate AND initialize the array for you at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of an array, you could construct a vector in this way:

```
vector<char> board(arraySize, '.');
```

Vectors can then be used like an array:

```
char c = board[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with that declaration is that you allocate memory at compile time using a size that is known only at run time. arraySize may change at anytime. If you say for example:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 50
char board[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

This way the size to be allocate is known at compile time and the compiler wont complain.
Then you can initialize using:  `memset(array, '.', size_of_array);`

Another option you allocate at runtime using `new` and use "value initialization" like this:

```
char * board = new char[arraySize]();
```

This will allocate AND initialize the array for you at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, the only way to achieve that would be to actually do what you posted char board[arraySize]={'.', '.','.'......(50 times)}, but actually copy and paste that '.' 50 times, which is a hassle and not smart. So the for loop works, or using vectors!

Answer (score 1):

Use std::array instead, then you can use fill.

```
#include <array>
[..]
std::array<char, 50> board;
board.fill('.');
```

But be aware, this is C++11 and internally there is a loop over your array, too. You get less and cleaner code, but it isn't faster.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is a C++ way to deal with array which size can be changed at run time:

```
std::vector<char> v( 50, '.'); // a vector with 50 dots
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

An option you have is to use `std::vector`, and specify the initial "fill" value in the proper constructor overload:

```
#include <vector> // For std::vector
....
std::vector<char> board(arraySize, '.');
```

If you really need a raw C array, you can always use `std::fill()` to simply fill it with some value:

```
#include <algorithm> // For std::fill
#include <iterator>  // For non-member std::begin and std::end 
....
static const int arraySize = 50;
char board[arraySize];
fill(begin(board), end(board), '.');
```

Another option is to use `std::array` (which is lightweight and zero-overhead like a raw C array, but offers a C++ STL interface too):

```
#include <algorithm> // For std::fill
#include <array>     // For std::array
....

static const int arraySize = 50;
std::array<char, arraySize> board;
std::fill(board.begin(), board.end(), '.');

// or just:
// board.fill('.');
// Since std::array has a fill() method.
```

(Frankly, in C++, I think that if you really need to use a statically-sized fixed-size array, `std::array` is better than raw C arrays.)